# How do I use awk to match multiple keys from 1 file in another file and print value from second file into first?

Tags: bash, awk

I need to match 2 columns from a source file with two columns from a reference file and print a third column from the reference file with all columns from the source file. Each pair in the source file (about 150,000 lines) only occurs once in the reference file (about 15,000,000 lines) and the files are large so I also need to stop searching the second file after the first instance (like grep -m 1). I have tried several attempts with awk and can get the search to work using only a single search key, but I need two keys as neither key is distinct by itself but the pairs are. The reference file is too large to load into R or python (25G as a gzipped file).

```
file 1 (source, multiple columns, 150K lines):
CHR SNP BP INFO(multiple other columns)
1 ABS141 132156 Random_stuff
2 GSD1151 132143 Random_stuff
3 KJH173 465879 Random_stuff

file 2 (reference, three columns, 25Gb gzipped):
CHR POS ID
1 132156 rid1
1 654987 rid2
2 132143 rid3
2 787987 rid4
3 465879 rid5

desired output file (all columns from file 1 + column 3 from file 2):
CHR SNP BP INFO(columns) ID
1 ABS141 132156 Random_stuff rid1
2 GSD1151 132143 Random_stuff rid3
3 KJH173 465879 Random_stuff rid5

Approaches tried:
awk 'NR==FNR {label[$1,$2]=$3; next} (sst[$1,$3]=label[$1,$2]){print $0, label[$1,$2]}' file2 file1 > out_file
Result = empty file

awk 'NR==FNR {seen[$1,$2]=$3; next} NR{print $0, seen[$1,$3]}' file2 file1 > out_file
Result = empty file

awk 'NR==FNR {label[$1,$2]=$3; next} ($1 SUBSEP $3 in label){print $0, label[$1,$2]}' file2 file1 > out_file
Result: empty file
    
awk 'NR==FNR {label[$1,$2]=$3; next} out[$1,$3] in label {print $0, label[$1,$2]}' file2 file1 > out_file
Result: empty file

awk 'NR==FNR {seen[$2]=$3; next} NF{print $0, seen[$3]}' file2 file1 > out_file
1 ABS141 132156 Random_stuff rid1
2 GSD1151 132143 Random_stuff rid3
3 KJH173 465879 Random_stuff rid5
Result = file with ID placed correctly into file 1 as new column, but only uses 1 key (POS) instead of 2 keys (CHR + POS).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a few tweaks to OP's 1st `awk` attempt:

```
awk '
NR==FNR          { if (FNR==1) $2="BP"                 # insure we can match on 2nd file header row
                   label[$1,$2]=$3
                   next
                 }
($1,$3) in label { print $0, label[$1,$3] }
' file2 file1
```

This generates:

```
CHR SNP BP INFO(multiple other columns) ID
1 ABS141 132156 Random_stuff rid1
2 GSD1151 132143 Random_stuff rid3
3 KJH173 465879 Random_stuff rid5
```

**NOTE:** this assumes OP can fit all of `file2` in memory; if this is an invalid assumption (eg, OP's code is running out of memory) then maybe ...

---

Assuming the entire expected result (ie, `file1`, plus field #3 from `file2`, plush hash of `file1` fields #1 & #3) can fit in memory, and we need to maintain the ordering of rows from `file1`, ...

One `awk` idea that requires a single pass through each input file:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { ndx=$1 FS $3
          if (FNR==1) ndx = "CHR" FS "POS"     # override ndx to match header from 2nd file
          lines[ndx]=$0                        # save current line in memory
          order[FNR]=ndx                       # save order of current line
          maxFNR=FNR                           # keep track of total number of lines from 1st file

          next
        }
        { ndx=$1 FS $2
          if (ndx in lines)                    # if there is a match in the lines[] array then ...
             lines[ndx]=lines[ndx] FS $3       # append current field #3 to lines[] entry
        }

END     { for (i=1;i<=maxFNR;i++)              # loop through lines from 1st file and ...
              print lines[order[i]]            # print to stdout
        }
' file1 file2
```

This generates:

```
CHR SNP BP INFO(multiple other columns) ID
1 ABS141 132156 Random_stuff rid1
2 GSD1151 132143 Random_stuff rid3
3 KJH173 465879 Random_stuff rid5
```

Comment: Thank you. I definitely can't load the entire file2 into memory. I expect to be able to load the rest into memory. However, on my test dataset I'm running into other issues:
1) As written, I get an empty file (when redirected to a file sted stdout)
2) When I rewrite the second set to "ndx2=$1 FS $2; if (ndx2 in lines)..." I get the new "ndx2" line appended as a new entry in the final column of the final line. The final line would look like:
3 KJH173 465879 Random_stuff ID rid1 rid3 rid5

Thoughts?

Comment: does the 2nd answer (processing `file1` first) not work on your sample data set?

Comment: it seems to process the files correctly, but only appends the ndx2 array to a new field in the final line of file1.

Comment: any chance the appended fields are showing up at the beginning of the lines? (wondering if you may have windows/dos line endings in one or both of your files) otherwise it sounds like there may be something different between your actual files and what's posted in the question ... consider running `head -5 file1 | od -c` and `head -5 file2 | od -c` so see if there are any odd characters (`\r`, control codes, etc) in your files

Comment: Not showing up at the beginning of the lines. The [od -c] output shows:
head -5 testdbsnp.txt | od -c
0000000   #   #   f   i   l   e   f   o   r   m   a   t   =   V   C   F
0000020   v   4   .   2  \n   #   #   f   i   l   e   D   a   t   e   =
0000040   2   0   2   1   0   5   1   3  \n   #   #   s   o   u   r   c
0000060   e   =   d   b   S   N   P  \n   #   #   d   b   S   N   P   _
0000100   B   U   I   L   D   _   I   D   =   1   5   5  \n   #   #   r
0000120   e   f   e   r   e   n   c   e   =   G   R   C   h   3   8   .
0000140   p   1   3  \n
0000144

Comment: And similar for the other file. The only escape backslash characters are for line breaks (\n). All files are created on an Ubunto for Windows virtual machine running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: that `od -c` output isn't anything like the sample files posted in the question; there's no header row and it looks like each line is of the format `##text=value\n` ... again, nothing like the format of the sample files provided in the question; at this point it looks (to me) like there are two different sets of file formats ... what's in the question ... what's in your `od -c` output ... ???

Comment: The only format difference between the question and the od -c inputs is that I only used a single whitespace character as delimiters, but the actual files contain several consecutively. As far as I understand, awk doesn't care about multiple whitespaces, but I could be wrong. Both files contain header lines: file1 does not start with a # and file2 starts with 36 lines of comments (lines begin ##). If I'm searching for keys, comment lines in the second file shouldn't affect the outcomes of the search, they just add 36 lines to the second array, right?

Comment: sure, extra lines in the array; but you're missing the point ... you've stated the `awk` scripts do not generate the desired result ... from my perspective it sounds like there may be some differences between actual data files and what's presented in the question ... not helping the analysis is the fact the `od -c` output does not cover any of the actual lines we're interested in; yes, I said `head -4` but that was based solely on the sample input file where the lines of interest start on lnie 1 (ie, the sample input files don't actually match the real files)

Comment: Thank you so much! Your last comment made me relook at the format of both outputs. The solution you provided is correct. The issue with me not making it work was solved by looking at a longer od -c output and assigning the correct field indices. For some reason, my counts were offset by 1.